# C: Define an array of long as return type of function

Tags: c, return-type

in C# I would just do:

```
private long[] myMethodName()
{
    //etc
}
```

What is the equivalent in C?

This gives an error:

```
long[] readSeqFile(char *fileName)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't any long[] you create in the method be on the stack (and thus toast as soon as you return)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for C you would pass a pointer and length

```
// returns number of elements written
size_t myMethodName(long* dest, size_t len)
{
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long *readSeqFile(char *filename);
```

You might want to make `filename` const:

```
long *readFileName(const char *const filename);
```

UPDATE: while this answers the original question, it's not very good C practise. If, as the poster says, he wants to read a list of integers from a file and get it back as an array of long, then the prototype is probably going to look something like this:

```
int readSeqFile(const char *const filename,long **longArray,size_t *const len);
```

and the implementation (in sketch form):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const size_t longArrayChunkSize=100;

int readSeqFile(const char *const filename,long **longArray, size_t *const len)
{
   FILE *fp;
   size_t nInts=0,curBufferLen;
   long tmp;

   fp=fopen(filename,"r");
   if(fp==NULL)
      return -1;

   *longArray=malloc(longArrayChunkSize*sizeof(long));
   if(*longArray==NULL)
      return -1;

   curBufferLen=longArrayChunkSize;

   // let's assume file is a list of integers, one per line
   while(read from file and !feof())
       {
       (scan line into tmp)
       longArray[nInts++]=tmp;
       if(nInts==curBufferLen)
          (realloc *longArray by longArrayChunkSize, increase curBufferLen)
       }

   *len=nInts;

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Call it like this: `result=readSeqFile(filename,&longArray,&arrayLen);` `longArray` is of type `long*` and it is the caller's responsibility to free it afterwards. The result is zero on success and -1 on error.

This is where you win with C++ and STL classes like `vector<long>` since you can just `push_back()` each long as it comes out of the file without having to worry about memeory management.

Comment: Who allocates the long*? Who deallocates?  Typically in C, the caller would be responsible for data allocation and destruction.

Comment: What I am trying to do is read in a file, populate a list of integers and return that to the caller.

Comment: Sure Josh, but the question was how do you return an array of long as the return type of a function. That's how you do it. In cases like this the array would probably be statically declared inside the function.

Comment: @DavidG, sure but I don't know if the OP understands the C pattern for this.  For a static array inside the function, you would most likely want to return a const long*.  For Matt's follow-up, to populate a list of integers and return to caller, then the caller should probably pass a pointer to where to put the data.  Look at memset or memcpy for the pattern.

Comment: Yes, after reviewing a few things.. I decided Josh had a better answer. I will still upvote this one as it was useful, but Josh's answer even more so.  Thanks both of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. I got it:

```
long *readSeqFile(char *fileName)
```

Thanks anyway

Comment: That is declared to return a *pointer*, not an *array*. Arrays and pointers are not the same thing. However, the formally right (and useless) answer is that in C and C++ it is impossible to declare a function that returns an object of built-in array type. Arrays are "non-returnable" in these languages.

Answer (score 0):

In C, functions cannot return array types; they can return *pointers* to arrays, such as

```
long (*readSeqFile(char *filename))[N]
{
  ...
}
```

the downside being that N must be a compile time constant if you're using a C89 or earlier compiler, or a C2011 compiler that doesn't support variable length arrays.  You *probably* don't want to go this route if you don't know how big the array is supposed to be ahead of time.